# ISC DHCP Server scope error

Tags: dhcp, isc-dhcp, dhcpd

Why am I getting the following error after modifying my dhcpd server config?

```
option space definitions may not be scoped
```

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs because scope options need to be defined in the top level of the configuration and not within any code block like a group:

```
#This needs to be defined outside of any code block
option space MSFT;
option MSFT.nbt                 code 1 = unsigned integer 32;
```